# Using the provider uid in firebase security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a Firebase application that only uses Google authentication. I want to give users that have never authenticated with my Firebase project access to parts of the database based on the uid of the auth provider. I want to retrieve the Google uids using the directory API and then store them in the whitelist node.

```
whitelist: {
  12345678: true,
  23456789`: true
},
data: {}
```

Then I would like to do something like this in the security rules:

```
"rules": {
  "data": {
    ".read": "root.child('whitelist/' + auth.providerUid).exists()
  }
}
```

Or something like this:

```
"rules": {
  "data": {
    ".read": "root.child('whitelist/' + auth.providerData[0].uid).exists()
  }
}
```

But is it possible to access the provider uid in the security rules? And if so, how does this work?

Comment: Why can't you use `auth.uid`?

Comment: Because I want to be able to whitelist G suite users before they have authenticated with the Firebase app. So the users I want to whitelist might not have a Firebase uid yet.

Comment: Interesting. I've only ever seen that type of whitelisting by email address. Do you see disadvantages to that compared to your approach?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen: The disadvantage I see there is that the email address cannot be used in the path because the dot is not allowed. Of course I could replace the dot by another character and then use a regex in the security rules to determine if access is allowed.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Just found that I can use the replace function to build a whitelist based on email addresses. Here is the example in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#replacesubstring_replacement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax seems slightly different according to the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken):

> `firebase.identities`
>
> Dictionary of all the identities that are associated with this user's account. The keys of the dictionary can be any of the following: `email`, `phone`, `google.com`, `facebook.com`, `github.com`, `twitter.com`. The values of the dictionary are arrays of unique identifiers for each identity provider associated with the account. For example, `auth.token.firebase.identities["google.com"][0]` contains the first Google user ID associated with the account

So it seems you need `auth.token.firebase.identities["google.com"][0]`. I must admit I've never used this though, since my security rules rely only on the user's main ID: `auth.uid`.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for  answering my question. I was just reading the same page in the docs but you posted a couple of seconds before me.

Comment: No worries, the docs are sometimes a bit hard to navigate. Let me know if it works, because I've never actually tried this.

Comment: Just my two cents, because this post comes at the top of the search. `google.com` does NOT work for Play Services login. If you want to authorise that one, you must use `playgames.google.com`. See: [`PlayGamesAuthProvider`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/PlayGamesAuthProvider)